# Почему цвет меняестся на белый?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть main camera в юнити проекте. Через скрипт я хочу сменить ей цвет. Он меняется, но на белый. Почему?

```
    public Camera camera;

    void Start()
    {
        camera = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (moneyGame == 20)
        {
            camera.backgroundColor = new Color(167, 120, 178, 255);
        }
    }
```

Вот скриншот цветов в инспекторе(ничего не трогал)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: new Color(167, 120, 178, 1); ???

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato не помогло, приложил скрин в правке

Comment: А может при получении GetComponent вы допускаете ошибку и такого компонента нет? Нарпимер назван не Camera а Canera

Comment: @Aarnihauta нет, стандартная main camera. Такой компонент там есть

Comment: Пройдитесь в дебаггере, поставьте точку остановки

Comment: Color(0-1, 0-1, 0-1, 0-1), Color32(0-255, 0-255, 0-255, 0-255)

Comment: Пройдитесь дебагом, или же напишите в консоль цвет и посмотрите, такой ли он

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) использует значения в диапазоне от 0 до 1. Все Ваши значения больше 1, следовательно цвет белый. Всё корректно. А вот структура [Color32](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) использует 32х-битный формат - поэтому можно использовать значения от 0 до 255.